# TSQL - Pivot not returning all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following JSON array data set that needs to be parsed into 2 table rows:

```
[        
  {           "eid": "ABCDGD",          
              "name": "Carol E",          
              "email": "carole@gmail.com",                        
              "role": "Recruiter"        
  },      
  {           "eid": "HDHDK",          
              "name": "Mark H",          
              "email": "markh@gmail.com",                       
              "role": "Manager"    
   }      
 ]
```

I need the code below to return both sets of employee information but it only returns one. How do I achieve this?

```
select p.* from 
(SELECT j2.[key] as _keys, j2.Value as _vals
FROM OPENJSON(@c) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.Value) j2
) as pds
PIVOT
(
  max(pds._vals)
  FOR pds._keys IN([eid], [name], [email], [role])
) AS p
```

SQLfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/54970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pivot, just specify your json columns and will give your desired results.

```
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@c) WITH (   
              eid   varchar(200)   '$.eid',  
              name  varchar(200)   '$.name',  
              email varchar(200)   '$.email',  
              role  varchar(200)   '$.role'
 ) j1
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is already maintaining a table kind structure in it and can be directly converted into table by using `OPENJSON`.

As the syntax of OPENJSON on MSDN website.

```
OPENJSON( jsonExpression [ , path ] )  [ <with_clause> ]

<with_clause> ::= WITH ( { colName type [ column_path ] [ AS JSON ] } [ ,...n ] )
```

Here just need to pass your column name as maintained in JSON and will convert your `JSON` into `SQL Table`.
You may find more details on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For your above query you may try this.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[        
  {           "eid": "ABCDGD",          
              "name": "Carol E",          
              "email": "carole@gmail.com",                        
              "role": "Recruiter"        
  },      
  {           "eid": "HDHDK",          
              "name": "Mark H",          
              "email": "markh@gmail.com",                       
              "role": "Manager"    
   }      
 ]'  

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH ( 
        eid nvarchar(50) '$.eid', 
        name nvarchar(50) '$.name', 
        email nvarchar(50) '$.email', 
        role nvarchar(50) '$.role', 
       )
```